# Redirect to other page based on datalist option(Reactjs)

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, datalist

I want to link to other page when one of them is selected. 
`

```
                {

                    this.state.datas.map((data,i)=>(

                        <option key={i} value={data.display_name}><Link to={"/search?q="+encodeURI  (data.name)} onClick={(e)=>this.clearData(data.name)}></Link></option>

                    ))
                }

                </datalist>`
```

Comment: Outline the problem you are facing.

Comment: I Have different option and when click on any option the page will change the problem is in <Link> as it is not working

Comment: So for that add your router config to the question. It depends if your route config is not correct, router won't behave correctly.

Comment: The problem is in Link tag as the same code when i use <ul><li> I worked perfect

Answer (score 0):

I've tried several options, including nesting **option** inside **Link** and vice versa, but pure html dropdowns don't seem to work well with React Router.

Here's a simple fix, though:

```js
this.state.datas.map((data,i) =>
<option 
  key={i} 
  value={data.display_name}
  onClick={(e) => {this.clearData(data.name); this.props.history.push("/search?q=" + encodeURI(data.name)) }}
>
{data.name} // Perhaps you were missing the stuff between the <option> tags too?
</option>)
```

If you've connected your component to the Router properly, you will have the **history** object in the component's props and be able to call **history.push** which will redirect the user to the newly specified route.

---

This creates an event listener on each dropdown option, so if you have lots of data, somewhat more performant approach would be to create another event handler in your class and attach it to the onChange listener of the **select** element.

```js
onChange = (event, data) => {
    this.clearData(data.name); 
    this.props.history.push("/search?q=" + encodeURI(data.name));
}
```

One more thing, avoid using index **i** as **key** because it can lead to unexpected issues with rendering. Try to find a value that's **globally unique** for the element you're rendering. For example, **data.data_id** would be a good **key** if you happen to have specified one in your database.

[More on dangers of index as key](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)